# Ferrite toroid vs E-core for high frequency transformers

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, magnetics

I found 2 ferrite rings in a power supply I was stripping for its magnetics. I was wondering why is it that I've never seen these employed as transformers.

I've read that for a number of reasons toroidal cores make superior transformers.

Why couldn't I employ these toroids in a half bridge or push-pull topology as opposed to the E-cores in the photo?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Why couldn't I employ these toroids in a half bridge or push-pull
> topology as opposed to the E cores in the photo?*

Three reasons that spring to mind: -

1. It's a lot easier to manually wind turns onto a bobbin then add that bobbin to the cores compared to manually winding a transformer on a toroid.
2. With core-sets, you can apply gapping to give you superior performance in many cases. Of course that's virtually impossible for a toroid. (It can be done but with difficulty).
3. An E-core set will have more volume of ferrite and be able to handle higher saturation currents for a given floor-area of a toroid.

> *I've read that for a number of reasons toroidal cores make superior
> transformers.*

That's not usually the case.

Comment: re: 1) There ARE toroidal transformer wiring machines. As mechanical engineering goes, they are high art!

Comment: @BrianDrummond I modded my answer to talk about "manually winding" because the op appears to be trying to salvage ferrites and that will likely be the only winding route open to them.

Comment: I thought airgaps were only used in inductors, Is there a case where you would gap a transformer (full/half bridge or push-pull)?

Comment: @user14828 No, they're used in transformers too. It's pretty general usage too I believe. I forget exactly why so just read this: https://www.powerelectronics.com/content/article/21861299/why-have-an-air-gap

Comment: @DKNguyen that article misses a very simple thing and, in that respect, it makes the article broadly wrong; adding a gap does reduce the risk of saturation. Here's why: say you added a gap and the permeability dropped 4 times and say you needed to keep a certain inductance on the primary; well you'd (only) need to double the turns to restore the inductance to the ungapped value. If the ungapped core was close to saturation on a certain supply voltage then quartering the perm and doubling the turns has an overall effect of halving the ampere turns hence, it unambiguously prevents saturations.

Comment: @user14828 sure there is and that is to prevent saturation as per the comment immediately above. I've wound several transformers that have used an airgap to reduce permeability and avoid saturation. For inductors it's even clearer.

Comment: @DKNguyen one of the reasons to use an air gap is to prevent saturation if there will be a DC current flowing through the transformer, for example like in single ended tube amplifiers.

Comment: @S.s. it doesn't matter if there is DC or not; you can add a gap to a transformer core, reduce the permeability, increase the turns to restore the required inductance and then you will have a net reduction in the effects of ampere turns. The math is simple and the effects are fundamental on any transformer type ferrite or not.

Comment: @Andyaka I absolutely love the clarity in your responses. Direct and simple. Together with your answer the whole is a +1 to my mind. So be it. You explain the value of the gap very easily and well. Nice! For those interested in a more detailed exposition, I recommend [this site](http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Workshop/advice/coils/gap/index.html). It covers some additional, interesting details such as ***Hanna curves***.

Comment: So, you add an airgap in increase your magnetizing force to get more current across, just like an inductor, correct?

Comment: @user14828 an air gap can significantly reduce the *effective* permeability of the core and give you more options when winding an inductor or transformer, especially at high frequencies. I think this series of comments have generally got a little side-tracked from your main question though.

Comment: I agree, but you've actually inadvertently answered a few other questions I've had for a long time now, because I've harvested a bunch of huge E cores from a some  digital HID ballasts that someone gave me. Most of the core halves have the center leg cut down, so I thought I was stuck with using the few that weren't cut to wind transformers and the rest as low ue inductors. Now I have 21 potential transformers as opposed to the 7 that I thought I had, thank you very much!

Comment: Make sure when reusing them you measure the inductance first and remember that final inductance is proportional to turns squared.

Comment: I  calculate for the μe the same way I do for an inductor right? You actually taught me to sand the center leg on an E core to make a boost inductor a few years back.

Comment: Yes you do and I remember that question (just about) LOL

Answer (score 0):

Sure Toroids make good transformers .In your case be careful .Cores that are for EMC often are made of materials that are deliberately designed to be more lossey  to absorb high frequencies .Such cores can give lower radiated EMI .If you use these as a transformer core heating will be a real problem and Power  supply efficiency will be down.